# Unable to POST file through curl using advanced rest client

Tags: php, rest, curl, postman, advanced-rest-client

Sending file to a php script works fine with curl from terminal but not through advanced rest client or postman.

Curl request-

```
curl -v --form filename=@/cus-check.json --form name=Upload http://127.0.0.1/cus.php
```

When sending the same request through ARC or Postman, the $_POST variable in php script returns an empty array.

Images

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Looks like there is an open bug on this one - https://github.com/jarrodek/ChromeRestClient/issues/945